# How to transfer a value that was given in a local scope to a global one in python

Tags: python-3.x, scope

Let me give an example:

```
H = 21 
def fun():
    H = input("Assume the input is 1")
print(H)
>>> 21
```

How do i make H = 1 which was the user input?
sometimes i want the local scopes to move to the global so that i can use them as place holders for other functions. Unless there are better ways i would like also help with that, thank you!

Comment: does my answer help you?

Comment: The first answer is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the H as global inside the function. Try:

```
H = 21 
def fun():
    global H
    H = input("Assume the input is 1")
```

Call the fucntion:

```
fun()
print(H)
```

Dont forget to use `int(input("Assume the input is 1"))` if you want to assign `H` an integer.

---

`Return` also helps:

```
H = 21 
def fun():
    return input("Assume the input is 1")
```

Now call:

```
H = fun()
print(H)
```